# How to get status of Windows 8.1 maintenance?

Tags: windows, windows-8, maintenance

How do I get the status (5% complete, 10% complete, etc.) for the Windows maintenance, once it is running? Can that be turned on, if it exists, when not running?

I am running Windows 8.1 Professional 64-bit.

I already know how to turn off maintenance, simply right click on the system tray maintenance running icon, select Open Action Center, and click on the stop hyperlink. Yes, I saw the maintenance "settings" link.

Windows maintenance started 2-days ago. I purposely did not turn off the computer. I merely lock the keyboard. Since I am not with the computer most of the time, the computer has had now 2-days to continuously do whatever it is doing and not finish. I have run defrag utilities in the past on other computers and that takes a fraction of the time that windows maintenance takes.

Comment: I removed your extra question regarding what the maintenance actually does to prevent this form being seen as a duplicate, as that part is already covered in this question: [What is the “Automatic Maintenance”?](http://superuser.com/questions/495336/what-is-the-automatic-maintenance)

Comment: I guess a follow up to the what is question that was removed is what exactly is ".Net Optimization" and how long does that usually take. One can also ask, which of the two tasks it is doing and as I asked at what percentage complete.

Comment: Your request for a status is a good/different question. As well, it's probably worth posting another new question that's just asking about what the ".Net Optimization" part is.

Comment: Good point, I did, question id is 725604.