# Windows 10 identify wake from sleep ethernet source

Tags: windows-10, wake-on-lan

I want wake from lan enabled for Ethernet (so I can access remotely without having to send a magic packet). With this configured in Windows 10, my computer sometimes wakes up every 20 - 40 minutes and then just stays awake. (There have been weeks when this doesn't happen...) I'd like to identify what port / program is getting accessed. Is there a way to debug the wake up event?

Here's powercfg lastwake information:

```
powercfg -lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Device
    Instance Path: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1503&SUBSYS_E0001458&REV_04\3&11583659&0&C8
    Friendly Name: Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
    Description: Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
    Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computer wakes by itself, but wake source is unknown](https://superuser.com/questions/751544/computer-wakes-by-itself-but-wake-source-is-unknown)

Comment: Wake source is Ethernet. Not sure why Ethernet is waking the system.

Comment: @nachum It could be any other device on your network sending an arp request.

Comment: @DavidPostill is there a way to discover what device?

Comment: You could use wireshark to monitor network traffic ...

Comment: @MichaelBay Not really a dupe, since we know it is the network card....

Comment: @DavidPostill Retracted.

Comment: @DavidPostill I was hoping for an easier solution. I'll look into Wireshark. Thanks