# Computer starts up seconds after shutting down

Tags: windows-10, bios, sleep, hibernate, wake-on-lan

Edit/Summary: I will not have physical access to the computer for the next month (it's at my parent's house and I live abroad), but from reading the comments, I believe a **deep cleaning** of the internals is a great suggestion, and I will as soon as I get back. I will also **replace the MB battery**, though the latter seems fine (read below for details). But if you have any proposed solutions that don't require physical access, please express them as I do have Teamviewer access.

I'm having a very weird issue where my computer instead of shutting down will blink for around 3-5 seconds (the sleep-state slow blink) and then it will start up/wake up again on its own. The same happens when I choose to "Sleep".

Things I have tried:

- Resetting Windows 10 using the Troubleshoot at boot
- Resetting BIOS settings to default (disabled wake on LAN)
- Updating all drivers. BIOS last official update Dec. 2015. Installed since early 2016
- Disallowing Wake Events to wake PC.
- Disabling Hibernate/Hybrid Sleep
- Checked all devices in Device Manager and disabled `Allow device to wake computer` when available (only the LAN driver had such an option).
- Removed all cables except mouse/keyboard/monitor. (no wifi)
- Checked the physical Power Button
- Disabled Windows Maintenance Activator and manually ran the maintenance tasks
- `powercfg waketimers` returns nothing
- `powercfg -DEVICEQUERY wake_armed` returns NONE
- Unfortunately I had System Restore disabled so I cannot restore to a previous point
- Threw away my very weak UPS and connected directly to power strip
- Cleaned the graphics card because its position seemed kind of odd. Rest of the insides have been last cleaned in December
- Checked condition of motherboard battery: it's fine (after draining the capacitors and cutting power to the PSU for a minute, system time is still correct (50ms ahead)). I will replace it anyway when I get back.

The issue still persists.

When I run `powercfg /lastwake` I get nothing useful (no wake source), and when browsing Event Viewer, I get `Wake Source: Unknown`.

Now I'm simply out of ideas. Could it be some kind of motherboard issue? This computer is 10+ years old (battery works fine), but it has been running Windows 10 fine since it came out, and the BIOS was last updated 2015.

Edit: I believe this question is not a duplicate of the one suggested because of two reasons:
- I have already read the whole post and the proposed solutions did not help my case.
- The duplicate answer suggested has no mention of shutdown issues: only sleep is mentioned.
- My issue occurs only seconds after sleep/shutdown regardless of time, suggesting that a scheduled task is not the issue. Therefore I believe that a different answer/solution is applicable.

Comment: Has it always done this or is something recent, we need more background info. Your bios may Not be compatible with W10 and there may be no cure on a 10 year old PC.

Comment: The computer has been running Windows 10 fine since it came out. The BIOS version is from 2015. This issue started about a month ago.

Comment: How is this a duplicate? It is a shutdown issue not a sleep issue. @harrymc

Comment: (1) Did you try [illicious’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/751544/150988#857605) (disassemble and clean)?  (2) Did you run `powercfg /waketimers` (mentioned in two answers)?  (3) Do you have Wi-Fi?  What have you done to verify that the Wi-Fi is not the source of the problem? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … If you’re going to say “the proposed solutions did not help my case”, we like to see specifics.  I have voted to reopen on general principles, but please [edit] your question to say specifically what you have tried.

Comment: Windows should be shutting down. If it doesn't then its a Windows problem. If the computer goes through the entire boot process I'd be very surprised but that would be a motherboard/bios problem. If its a Windows problem, it might be best to nuke it and do a fresh install with latest download image - of course, it could be a recent update and then that would be a problem. No one here will probably know so I think only testing will help. Suppose too maybe some Windows bug where it didn't actually shutdown properly might also cause pc to go through full boot (maybe but doubtful)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm away from home. The only thing I haven't tried is the cleaning. Any specific component I should focus on? I threw away my faulty UPS and now it's plugged directly to the strip. I will not have physical access to this PC for another month.

Comment: @GM 180 When the time permits, you should try scanning the whole computer for malware.

Comment: @Jim I will do that right away - I have teamviewer access!

Comment: Double check the power button. But before, check the power supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem - it was the BIOS battery. It seemed to hold a charge when I first tested it, but I guess the voltage was too low. Replacing it fixed the weird behavior.